# how to pass reference of JQuery source to child page in iframe from main page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, iframe

I have a main page in which I have an iframe. Inside this iframe i am adding a child page.

Sample code as below.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi from main');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <iframe id="iframe1" runat="server" src="Child.aspx"></iframe>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note that I have added Jquery reference here.

Now my child page has code as below:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            alert('hi from child');
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My questions are

why alert in main is getting displayed while in child page it says $
    is undefined.
How can I pass JQuery source reference to child page without adding
    below line in child page

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Why not use `<asp:Content>` instead of `iFrame`?

Answer (score 0):

You can not. iFrame is designed to accommodate other sites.